# are Gazebo IMU's measures sufficiently good?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I used  morse (simulator) in order to simulate a car with IMU inside. I found that IMU's measures was not good when I integrated them.  because :

1. Frequency (100 Hz) wasn't respected
2. Gravity wasn't stable,
3. I think values on all axes were also bad and unrealistic

Do you think that you simulator can do better ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208076/are-gazebo-imu%27s-measures-sufficiently-good-?/) by [user](https://answers.ros.org/users/22289/user/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-30**:
@user: I've changed the title of your question to better reflect the contents. Gazebo is not 'our' (ROS's) simulator, but actually only one of many you can use. For Gazebo specific questions, I'd recommend you use [answers.gazebosim.org](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/).

**Comment by [user](https://answers.ros.org/users/22289/user/) on 2015-05-06**:
thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are also simulated IMUs in Gazebo that you could try out. Integrating IMU data for a prolonged amount of time only really works well for high grade systems such as those used in the aerospace industry. It might be (not sure) that MORSE deliberately  adds noise to the simulated measurements to provide more realistic simulation of lower cost IMUs, as these are far more common for robotics use.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0